# limit drag of multiple divs within respective container divs - jquery draggable

Tags: jquery, user-interface, draggable, containment

I have 3 divs (draggable), each inside its (container) div. I am able to limit the movement of one div using "containment", but when it comes to 3 having the same classes, it doesn't work. Any help on how this can work? here is a quick fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/B63Px/8/

Answer (score 1):

When you provide a selector as a containment, it only contains it to the first element that matches the selector.

Unless I am misunderstanding, it appears that you are wanting to contain the div according to it's parent. In that case, you should use

```
containment: "parent"
```

[You can see this in action on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/YqGJS/)

Comment: thanx alot peter, that's what i was trying to do

Comment: one more thing if you dont mind, how did u make that work in fiddle? the one i posted isn't working in fiddle. (p.s. though i have change liveDraggable to draggable)

Comment: hey, appreciate your reply. i want to use something like "parent.class" to achieve this http://jsfiddle.net/YqGJS/1/ but seems not possible. any help?

Comment: i am trying to move the green div from the first td to the second